# Use predicate in stream Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I can't understand, how to build predicate for `stream`. 
Have class:

```
public class User {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String firstName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String secondName;
}
```

Also, I have class for Predicates:

```
public final class Predicates {

    private Predicates() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a predicate, Not
     */
    public static <T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        return predicate.negate();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a predicate, isNull
     */
    public static <T> Predicate<T> isNull(Object o) {
        return (o == null)
                ? ObjectPredicate.IS_NULL.callback()
                : ObjectPredicate.ALWAYS_FALSE.callback();
    }

    //Enum for predicate object
    enum ObjectPredicate implements Predicate<Object> {
        IS_NULL {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Object o) {
                return o == null;
            }
        },
        ALWAYS_FALSE {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Object o) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        <T> Predicate<T> callback() {
            return (Predicate<T>) this;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I wanna use something like this:

```
List<User> users = getSomeUserList();
Booleant check = users.stream().anyMatch(Predicate.isNull(User::getSecondName));
```

Help me understand, what I doing wrong.

Comment: start by stating what you expect and what actually happens.

Comment: A `Predicate` is meant as a test, which, given any object extending `T`, should return true or false based on some characteristic of that object. If a `Predicate` always returns the same value, use a boolean instead (the `Predicate` `isNull()` shouldn't have any parameters and should have a function to take a value and return true if it is `null`, whereas the `boolean` `isNull()` is essentially the `test()` function of the `Predicate` - it takes a value and returns true if it's `null`).

Comment: You are mixing up functions and imperative code and you’re doing it several times within that small piece of code. Nevertheless, the purpose of this baroque code is completely unclear. Why not simply use `users.stream().anyMatch(u -> u.getSecondName()==null)` or why creating your own methods/ functions for mirroring the existing idioms `Objects::isNull`, `x->false` and `Predicate.negate()`…

Comment: How can I change this line `.stream().filter(Predicates.not(UserStatus.NOT_CONFIRMED::equals))` with use `Predicate.negate()`?

Comment: `Predicate.isEqual(UserStatus.NOT_CONFIRMED).negate()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` to map your `Stream<User>` to a `Stream<String>` and then use your predicate to search for a match :

```
Boolean check = users.stream()
                     .map(User::getSecondName)
                     .anyMatch(Predicates::isNull);
```

Comment: Not really. That `Predicates.isNull` method return a `Predicate`, not a `boolean`. You could use the standard `Objects::isNull` or simply `users.stream().anyMatch(u -> u.getSecondName()==null)` but it’s not clear whether this will help the OP regarding whatever is intended (a learning effect, I guess)…

Comment: Yes, I used a simple form like you said, but I wanna to know, how to work with the `Predicate` like in `Guava`, but with the stream. And code on top, I think to write much better: `Boolean check = users.stream().map(User::getSecondName).anyMatch(Objects::isNull);`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public static <T, R> Predicate<T> isNull(Function<T, R> mapper) {
        return new Predicate<T> {
            @Override
            boolean test(T o) {
               return ObjectPredicate.IS_NULL.callback().test(mapper.apply(o));
            }
        }
}
```